# AttributeError: __enter__ em implementação de gerenciador de contexto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou tentando entender o funcionamento dos **`gerenciadores de contexto`** do Python, implementando um baseado no **`contextmanager`**. Aqui segue o script:

```
class contextmanager(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('__call__')
        self._gen = self._func(*args, **kwargs)
        return self.__enter__()

    def __enter__(self):
        print('__enter__')
        return next(self._gen)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
        print('__exit__')
        next(self._gen)


import os

@contextmanager
def changepath(path):
    actual = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(path)
    yield
    os.chdir(actual)


with changepath('downloads') as path:
    print(os.getcwd())
print(os.getcwd())
```

Mas a saída é:

```
__call__
__enter__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thiaguinho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Code\NIGHT\_eigth_asyncio.py", line 99, in <module>
    with changepath('downloads') as path:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Alguém pode me dizer onde está o erro ?

Sim.

Nesta linha dentro do `__call__`:

```
    return self.__enter__()
```

O objeto que o `with` vai usar tem que ter um método `__enter__`. Ele é chamado automaticamente pela linguagem, na execução do comando `with`.  Ou seja, essa linha deveria simplesmente retornar `self`.  O método `__enter__` do objeto vai ser chamado logo em seguida pela linguagem.  Quando você chama o `__enter__` diretamente, o código vai executar a função decorada até o `yield` e retornar, como valor do `__next__` o valor enviado pelo `yield` - que como está em branco, é `None`. Na sequência, o Python tenta chamar o `__enter__` nesse valor `None`, e aí ocorre o seu erro.

Via de regra, todos os métodos que são sinalizados pelos dois *underscores* no início e no final (os chamados "*dunder methods*") são chamados pela linguagem, e não explicitamente pelo programador.

Ademais, para quem está tentando "entender o comando `with`", você está reimplementando uma função que existe na `contextlib` da biblioteca padrão e que faz um uso bem avançado de propriedades dos geradores para permitir que sejam implementados com a sintaxe de uma função - não sei se é a forma mais didática de se entender o `with`. O uso simples é com uma *classe*  que tenha os métodos `__enter__`  e `__exit__` que façam diretamente o que você pretende ao entrar e sair do bloco `with`.

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez jsbueno